# pgfplots: How can I write square brackets in xlabel or ylabel?

Tags: pgfplots, brackets

The following works fine:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xlabel=$k$, ylabel=$x(k)$]
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,4) (2,2) (3,-1) (4,2)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But as soon as I replace `$x(k)$` with `$x[k]$`, I get an error.

Is it possible to use square brackets in xlabel or ylabel?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ensure you put the labels within braces:

```
xlabel={$k$}, ylabel={$x[k]$}
```

From the PGFPlots manual, on page 200, you have the following

> ```
> /pgfplots/xlabel={<text>}
> /pgfplots/ylabel={<text>}
> /pgfplots/zlabel={<text>}
> ```

Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xlabel={$k$}, ylabel={$x[k]$}]
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,4) (2,2) (3,-1) (4,2)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```